# retrieving selected (using checkbox )row data of a dynamic table created using json objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, checkbox

I have a table which is created dynamically using the JSON data from backend.There is a checkbox column used to retrieve the data from a particular row. Once the checkbox is checked, I need to get the row data in an array using Javascript.I have the below code, when I check a checkbox I am not able to fetch the row data or not able to get the alert as in the code.  Can anyone help me to correct this ?

HTML Code:

```
<table id="playerList"class="table table-bordered"style="background-color:#black;" >
            <thead style="background-color:#22b14c;">
              <tr >
                <th style="width:20px;"><input id='checkbox1' class='case' name='case[]' type='checkbox' ></input></th>
                <th style="width:200px">Player</th>
                <th style="width:200px;">Score</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="background-color:#black;" >


            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

show_PlayerLimits();
$('.case').click(function(){
    var row = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
    $(row).each(function(){

        alert("in a row");
    });
});
function show_PlayerLimits(){
                    $.ajax({   
                        url: "http://localhost:8080/API/admin/getAllPlayers",
                        method: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            /* Authorization header */
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", localStorage.accessToken );

                        },
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log(response);
                            //alert("success position");
                            if(response.success==true){
                                data=response.users;
                                console.log(data);
                                 len=response.users.length;
                                 user=response.users;
                                 console.log(len);
                                  $.each(data,function(i,user){
                                    $('tr:odd').addClass('odd');
                                        var tblRow =
                                            "<tr>"
                                            +"<td><input name='chk[]' type='checkbox' class='chk' value='"+user.id+"'/></td>"
                                            +"<td>"+user.player+"</td>"
                                            +"<td>"+user.score+"</td>"

                                            +"</tr>";

                                            $(tblRow).appendTo("#playerList");

                                            });

                                    $('#playerList').DataTable();

                                console.log(data);
                                console.log(response.users[1].player);
                                console.log(response.users[0].score);
                                console.log(response.users.length);

                            }   
                            else
                            {
                                alert(response.message);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(textStatus,errorThrown);
                        }
            })




            return false;
            }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.case').click(function()
```

This function will trigger when you check the header row checkbox(i was able to get the alert box using your code). But i see that you are adding checkboxes in each row dynamically, but assigning class="chk" to those checkboxes. Either change the above function to `$('.chk').click(function()` or asssign the class="case" to all the checkboxes in the table.

Update: 
Working example posted here. On each checkbox checked, background color of the corresponding row will be changed. I have also added a new button to Add new row in order to demonstrate the click event handler for dynamically created elements post page load.

```
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
         show_PlayerLimits();
         $('#addRow').click(function () {
            var rowCount = $('#playerList tr').length - 1;
            var tblRow =
               "<tr>"
               + "<td><input name='chk[]' type='checkbox' class='chk' value='" + rowCount + "'/></td>"
               + "<td>Player " + rowCount + "</td>"
               + "<td>" + rowCount + " runs</td>"
               + "</tr>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#playerList");
            $('#playerList').find('[value="' + rowCount + '"]').click(changeCheckedRowColor);
         })
         function show_PlayerLimits() {
            for (var count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
               $('tr:odd').addClass('odd');
               var tblRow =
                  "<tr>"
                  + "<td><input name='chk[]' type='checkbox' class='chk' value='" + count + "'/></td>"
                  + "<td>Player " + count + "</td>"
                  + "<td>" + count + " runs</td>"
                  + "</tr>";
               $(tblRow).appendTo("#playerList");
            }
            $('.chk').click(changeCheckedRowColor);
         }
         function changeCheckedRowColor() {
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               $(row).attr('style', 'background-color:blue');
            }
            else $(row).removeAttr('style');
         }
      });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <table id="playerList" class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:black;">
      <thead style="background-color:#22b14c;">
         <tr>
            <th style="width:20px;"><input id='checkbox1' class='case' name='case[]' type='checkbox'></input>
            </th>
            <th style="width:200px">Player</th>
            <th style="width:200px;">Score</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="background-color:white;">
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This still won't work for dynamically created elements - the array of elements is built on page load prior to them actually existing.

Comment: For dynamically created elements post page load, you need to add a click handler after its creation. `$('.chk').click(getRowElementsinArray);` Define a function getRowElementsinArray() and add your logic there.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your click event call on the check boxes won't fire for dynamically added elements as the array within `$('.case')` is built on page load - this is before the elements are created by the JavaScript code.

The solution is using the dynamic event method in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.case', function(){
// Your function...
}
```

Using this method jQuery will begin to execute the handler when a click is made on the document (ie anywhere on the page) but will only fire your defined function if the event sender (the clicked object) matches the provided query.

Edit:

As per the comment by @PrashanthBR you could also apply the event handler after you generate your new checkbox and append it to the page.